# Changing the position of modeline

Tags: emacs, customization, emacs23, modeline

Is it possible to change the position of modeline so that it appears at the top of the buffer instead of at the bottom of the main buffers? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a [header-line](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html#Header-Lines), and turn off the [mode-line](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data) with:

```
(setq-default header-line-format mode-line-format)
(setq-default mode-line-format nil)
```

This seems to do what (I think) you want for basic usage at least.  Opening new files and buffers keeps the header line in place and doesn't have a mode line.

Read more of the documentation about [Mode-Line Format](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html).